Is it true that in a triangle, if $a$ is the smallest side then $P\left(Rr > \frac{a^2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$?
I found this curious geometric probability expeerimentally. Can this be proved or disproved?
Let $a$ be the smallest side of a triangle whose inradius is $r$ and vertices are uniformly random on circle of radius $R$. Experimental data for $10^9$ simulations show that the probability
$$
P\left(Rr > \frac{a^2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

I have some initial thoughts. Denote by $\Delta$ the area of the triangle with sides $a,b,c$, and denote $s=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}$. There are the identities $$\Delta = \dfrac{abc}{4R}$$ and $$\Delta = r \cdot s$$ which together give us $$Rr = \dfrac{abc}{4s} = \dfrac{abc}{2(a+b+c)}.$$ With this, the event $Rr > \dfrac{a^2}2$ is equivalent to $$bc > a(a+b+c).$$

Partial answer.
Let:

$P_1=P\left(\frac{ac}{b}>a+b\right)$ where $a,b,c$ are the triangle's side lengths in random order
$P_2=P\left(\frac{ac}{b}>a+b+c\right)$ where $a,b,c$ are the triangle's side lengths in random order
$P_3=P\left(\frac{ac}{b}>a+b+c\right)$ where $b$ is the triangle's smallest side length

It can be shown that $P_1=\frac14$. (In the link, it is assumed that $\frac{a}{b}>1$ and $P\left(\frac{ac}{b}>a+b\right)$ is shown to be $\frac12$. Now if $\frac{a}{b}<1$ then $P\left(\frac{ac}{b}>a+b\right)=0$ by the triangle inequality. So $P_1=\frac14$.)
A simulation suggests that $P_2=\frac16$. I suspect that the method in the above link can be used to prove this, because $P_1$ and $P_2$ are similar in form.
It can be shown that $P_3=3P_2$, by the following argument. If $b$ is not the triangle's smallest side length, then assuming (without loss of generality) that $a$ is the triangle's smallest side length, we must have $\frac{ac}{b}<c<a+b+c$, that is, $P\left(\frac{ac}{b}>a+b+c\right)=0$. So $P_3=3P_2$.
Euclid's comment to the OP shows that $P_3$ is equivalent to the probability in the OP (note that I'm calling the smallest side length $b$ instead of $a$).
This would show that the probability in the OP is indeed $\frac12$.

The OP may be a good question for my list of probability questions that have answer $\frac12$ but resist intuitive explanation.
